# $|F^* - \tilde F^*| \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, nonlinear-optimization

> Define $F^* := \max\limits_{x\in [0, \alpha]} F(x),\quad \tilde F^* := \max\limits_{x\in [0, \tilde \alpha]} F(x)$. Assume that $F(x)$ is continous function and $|\alpha -\tilde \alpha| \leq \epsilon$. How can get the upper bound of $|F^*-\tilde F^*|$ such that this upper bound will imply $|F^*-\tilde F^*| \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?

I have no idea to solve it. Please give me some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you know that the max function is continuous as well if F is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Define $F^*(\alpha):=max_{x \in [0,\alpha]}F(x)$.
This is an continuous function (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213682/is-the-maximum-function-of-a-continuous-function-continuous)), because $F$ is continuous. It also holds $F^*(\bar{\alpha})= \bar{F}^*(\bar{\alpha})$, so to be precise, both functions are the same, they are just calculated at different points on the intervall. 
The proof simply follows by continuity of $F^*$:
Now say without loss of generality $\alpha = \bar{\alpha}- \epsilon$:
 $|F^*(\alpha)-\bar{F}^*(\bar{\alpha})|=|F^*(\alpha)-F^*(\alpha + \epsilon)| \rightarrow 0$, as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Comment: how can you prove that $F^*(\alpha)$ is continous?

Comment: [look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213682/is-the-maximum-function-of-a-continuous-function-continuous)

Comment: If function $F$ is Lipchitz with constant $L$. Can we show that $|F^*(\alpha) - F^*(\bar \alpha) | \leq L\delta$?

Comment: well I guess you mean $\epsilon$ instead of $\delta$, that would be the definition of Lipschitz continuity. But this functions $F^*$ is not necessarily Lipschitz ( and you dont need it to be).