# how to prove $g(x) = \max\{f(y) : a \le y \le x \}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For the continuous function $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$

Let $g(x) = \max\{f(y) : a \le y \le x \}. x\in[a,b]$ Show $g(x)$ is continuous

I tried to use $\epsilon\text{-}\delta$ first, but I failed.
I thought that this function is continuous because of pasting lemma.
Can you give me a few hints to show this.. ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213682/is-the-maximum-function-of-a-continuous-function-continuous

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Fix $x \in [a,b]$, let $I$ denote the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. Note that
$$
\sup \{|g(y_1) - g(y_2)|: y_1,y_2 \in I\} \leq \sup \{|f(y_1) - f(y_2)|: y_1,y_2 \in I\}
$$
and that by the triangle inequality,
$$
\sup \{|f(y_1) - f(y_2)|: y_1,y_2 \in I\} \leq 2 \sup\{|f(y) - f(x)| : y \in I\}.
$$
This should help you set up an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved it through your hints!