# Monotonicity and boundedness of $F(x)=\max_{t\in [a,x]}f(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:[a,b)\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Define $F:[a,b)\to \mathbb R$ by $F(x)=\max_{t\in [a,x]}f(t)$. Then state true or false for the following:
> $1$) $F(x)$ is continuous and necessarily monotonic.
> $2$) $F(x)$ is necessarily bounded.

Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,x]$ as well, then $F(x)$ is also a continuous function. Here [Is the maximum function of a continuous function continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213682/is-the-maximum-function-of-a-continuous-function-continuous) is a descriptive solution for the same. When it comes to the $F(x)$ being monotonic and if it is a constant then it is true ( but bounded as well). I think that $F(x)$ will be monotonic (by IVP no any jumps will be there). I am not sure if it is bounded. Need a hint for a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: **Hint :** if $I \subset J$, then $\max_I(f(t)) \leq \max_J(f(t))$.

Comment: Take $f:[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= \frac{1}{1-x}$. In this case $F(x)=f(x)$, which shows that $F$ can be unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already provide a reference that establishes the continuity of $F$, I'll just gather the comments to provide an answer.

1. The function $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1-x}$, for which we have $F(x)=f(x)$, provides a counterexample for the boundness of $f$. Hence, 2) is false.
2. Taking $a \leq x_1 \leq x_2 < b$, we have that
   $$
   F(x_1)=\max_{t \in [a,x_1]}f(t) \leq \max_{t \in [a,x_1]\cup[x_1,x_2]}f(t) = \max_{t \in [a,x_2]}f(t) = F(x_2),
   $$
   which justifies that $F$ is non decreasing.